# Need to replace � with space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting constantly changing text from a website and putting that into an HTML file then having the program read that Html file and find the text and input it into a .txt file but when I input it into the file the spaces are replaced with �, Some people on discord helped me write one that removes them and they are gone but now they have no spaces and are just one long word. I need help replacing the �'s with spaces. This is the code I currently have. If anyone is wondering it is, it is supposed to read text from Nitro Type and I know it probably isn't very efficient I don't need it to be I just need to replace the question marks with spaces and .replace() doesn't work with it. Sorry if this is a simple fix I'm super new to coding. FYI this isn't the full code the rest of it works.

```
with open("word.html", "r") as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
words = soup.find_all('span', class_='dash-letter')
stuff = ""
for span in words:
    if span.text.isascii():
        stuff += span.text
with open("Sentence.txt", "w") as wf:
    wf.write(stuff)
```

Comment: The `�` character is '\ufffd', the unicode replacement character.  You can replace it with `mystring.replace('\ufffd`, ' ')`.  However the presence of this character suggests that the problem is that the website's HTML is not being decoded properly, so ideally  you should fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an optimal solution but meets your need

```
 for span in words:

    if span.text.isascii():
        stuff += span.text
     else:
        stuff += ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help I solved the problem I realized I could just replace the entity in the HTML with ' ' and then It would be a lot easier thanks for the help though.